# Frequent restarts on Google App Engine Standard second generation

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a problem with frequent restarts of App Engine instances which last for 15-30 minutes, sometimes maybe 1 hour.

Last 24 hours, we had 72 instance restarts. We have looked into the logs, but can't find any error messages explaining this.

`Min_instances` is set to `1`.

The app is a PHP Codeigniter app running on the `php73` runtime.

Maybe this is relevant as it shows up regularly in the log, not at the same time as web requests :

```
A 2020-05-01T17:46:46.675532Z [start] 2020/05/01 17:46:46.674713 Quitting on terminated signal 
A 2020-05-01T17:46:46.900441Z [start] 2020/05/01 17:46:46.899377 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit
```

Looking at the request log it looks like there is no pattern in page requests that could lead to instances crashing.

All page-requests load in typically 1-80 ms, there are no heavy scripts. It looks like the instances crash while idle.

We have also tried to increase the instance type to `F4` with the same results.

The graphs for CPU usage and memory usage don't give us any clue.

The problem with this is loading requests for site visitors. Most of the time the site is fast and responsive, but it is possible with accidental loading times of 1s+ when new instances start. We have set up warm up requests, but that does not cover all instance starts.

Is this a normal behavior ? How can we debug further ? Any clue what can be wrong ?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Here is our app.yaml:

```
runtime: php73
entrypoint: serve public_html/index.php

instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1

inbound_services:
- warmup

vpc_access_connector:
  name: "xx"

handlers
- url: /
  script: auto
  secure: always

- url: /(.+)
  script: auto
  secure: always  

env_variables:
  CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: xx
  REDIS_HOST: xx
  REDIS_PORT: xx
```

Comment: Could you post your app.yaml? This could be a scaling configuration issue

Comment: Did you solve the problem? We run into the same issue...

Comment: We are experiencing the same behaviour for `go113` environment. Don't know why is this happening either. We have filled support request @Google

Comment: We have not solved it yet, instances are still short-lived. I have done some load tests and I see that the instance can handle up to 60-70 reqs/s before scaling up, so it does not look like instance load has anything to do with it.

Comment: Hitting the same on python37, so its not language specific. Also my app.yaml is very very minimal. I think the only thing I have in there is warmup, so maybe that's somehow related?

Comment: I have been in touch with Google, and after some investigation they found that it may be caused by some intermittent problems on the App Engine server we are on. They are looking to move us to another server. Will report back on further development.

Comment: I've been having the same issue, below is my `app.yml` for reference:

`runtime: java11
    instance_class: F4_1G
    automatic_scaling:
      max_instances: 1
    env_variables:
      APP_NAME: ${APP_NAME}`

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause? I have the same issue with Java 11 runtime. I recently migrated from Java 8 to 11 runtime and immediately noticed this issue. The F1 Java 8 runtime was much more stable even though technically it had only 128MB RAM. The F1 Java 11 runtime (second gen) has twice the RAM at 256MB.

Comment: No, did not find the root cause. It improved after I talked to the GAE support, but not exactly sure what they did or if they did anything. Maybe the platform was just unstable for some time. Now everything works very well and stable.